# About the YAxis、Series of TeeChart（platform,WP8）

Tags: windows-phone-8, teechart

Platform：wp8

If I drag the series and move by the x-Axis，the x-Axis will move together. But if I do it by the y-Axis ,the y-Axis will not move with the Series. I must drag the y-Axis，then the series will move together with the y-Axis.How can I code it manually？

If I set the min, max of y-Axis or x-Axis，I still can drag the series out of min、max bound.How can I prevent this？
（It's pity ，there are no special docs for wp8，and other examples of other platform ruan quit differently in wp8. I have read almost every doc of TeeChart available，and run the examples in wp8）.
I think I can not handler it, please help,thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I'm going to need a little more detail of what you're trying to achieve before being able to help you further. Would you be so kind as to tell me the code you are running? Could you also clarify your question with some annotated images of the behaviour you would like to see?

Comment: I just run the example,"TeeChart Pro.NET Tutorials →Tutorial4 Axis Control→ Multiply Custom Axes".I have already corrected something different such as "Color.Red" to "Colors.Red",it runs out very different in wp8.I cannot upload the pic,please just run it and help，thanks.I am sure things run quite different in wp8，so please help.What I want to work out is something like the example-"Financial -MACDFunction" at [link](http://www.steema.com/gallery/charts/27),but what a pity it is just a pic!And I don't want the user to drag the series by YAxis,but I cann't control in wp8.HELP@ChristopherIreland

Comment: The chart in WP8 also don't have the property of "AllowPanning"！！Too many differences！！！@ChristopherIreland

Comment: "Important differences between TeeChart .NET for Windows Phone and other TeeChart versions

"As far as we know, everything that can be done with TeeChart on other platforms can also be done on WP with either pinch and drag deactivated (GestureOptions = Gestures.None) or by using the FullChart pinch and drag (GestureStyle = GestureStyles.FullChart). With the InChart pinch and drag activated (GestureStyle = GestureStyles.InChart and GestureOptions != Gestures.None) there are going to be instances in which some techniques of working with TeeChart are valid in all platforms other than WP.""

Comment: Adding the following line to the example you mention: " tChart1.Aspect.GestureOptions = Steema.TeeChart.Silverlight.Drawing.Aspect.Gestures.None;" makes TChart render identically in both Windows Forms and Windows Phone.